# edge is not displaying background color on a:link

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

https://fivosm.github.io/ tested on ie, firefox, chrome works fine, the a:link's background is red. In edge though the background is not red until I hover over it.

I don't know where to start, my google searches don't show anything related to my problem.
Here is my [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/XLW4qvbA), just in case the formatting is messed up again

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="57x57" href="favicons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" /><link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="favicons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" /><link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="favicons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" /><link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="favicons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" /><link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="60x60" href="favicons/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png" /><link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="120x120" href="favicons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" /><link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="76x76" href="favicons/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" /><link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="152x152" href="favicons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" /><link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicons/favicon-196x196.png" sizes="196x196" /><link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicons/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96" /><link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" /><link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" /><link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicons/favicon-128.png" sizes="128x128" /><meta name="application-name" content="&nbsp;"/><meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFFFFF" /><meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="favicons/mstile-144x144.png" /><meta name="msapplication-square70x70logo" content="favicons/mstile-70x70.png" /><meta name="msapplication-square150x150logo" content="favicons/mstile-150x150.png" /><meta name="msapplication-wide310x150logo" content="favicons/mstile-310x150.png" /><meta name="msapplication-square310x310logo" content="favicons/mstile-310x310.png" />
    <meta name="description" content="All of my projects are stored here" />
        <title>FivosM Projects</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">
            <style>

                body {
                    backgroundColor = "#f5f5f5";                    
                    font-family: sans-serif;
                    text-align: center;
                    text-align: center;
                    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;                    
                }
                .background{
                    -webkit-background-size: cover;
                    -moz-background-size: cover;
                    -o-background-size: cover;
                    background-size: cover;                     
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;                       
                }
                div {
                    border-radius: 25px;
                    width: 270px;
                    height: 370px; 
                    display: inline-block;
                    white-space: normal;
                    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #828282;

                }
                h1 {
                text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #d3d3d3;

                }
                small { 
                    font-size: smaller;

                }
                .transparent{
                    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
                }   

                a:link {
                    background-color: #f44336;
                    color: white;
                    padding: 3px 6px;
                    text-align: center; 
                    text-decoration: none;
                    display: inline-block;

                }
                a:visited {
                    background-color: #7b77ff;
                    color: white;
                    padding: 3px 6px;
                    text-align: center; 
                    text-decoration: none;
                    display: inline-block;

                }

                a:hover, a:active{
                    background-color: red;

                }
                a:disabled, a[disabled]{
                    color: black;
                    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    text-decoration: underline;

                }   
            </style>
</head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changebackground() {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#f5f5f5";
                var viewport_w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
                var viewport_h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
                var geturl = "url(https://source.unsplash.com/category/nature/" + viewport_w + "x" + viewport_h + ")";
                document.body.style.backgroundImage = geturl;
        }
    </script>
 <body class="background" onload="changebackground();">
  <div class = "body animated bounceInDown transparent">
    <h1>My Projects: </h1>
    <h3> Software: </h3>
    <p><b>Pinger:</b> <a 
 href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/FivosM/Pinger/12b37fe2/Pinger.bat" target="_blank" download="Pinger"> Download </a> &nbsp; <a 
  href="https://github.com/FivosM/Pinger" target="_blank"> Github </a></p>
    <h3> Games: </h3>
    <p><b>HellBlocks:</b> <a href="https://fivosm.itch.io/hellblocks" target="_blank"> Itch.io page </a></p>
    <h3> Websites: </h3>
     <p><b>This website:</b> <a href="https://fivosm.github.io" target="_blank" > fivosm.github.io </a></p>
     <p><small><a href="https://github.com/FivosM" target="_blank" 
 disabled="true"> Github </a> | <a href="https://fivosm.itch.io/" target="_blank" 
   disabled="true"> Itch.io </a> </small></p>
     </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What colour is the background link before you hover over it?

Comment: `backgroundColor = "#f5f5f5";` should be `background-color: #f5f5f5`. Don't mix up javascript syntax with css. This is not an answer to your question, just a note

Comment: the colour is red. This is what happens on edge: http://prntscr.com/g8swvz This is what happens in chrome, ie and firefox: http://prntscr.com/g8sxwq

Answer (score 0):

Define the background for a. Also you have a:visited style setting the background color to #7b77ff. Remove that if you don't need it for a link button styling.

```
a{
background-color: #f44336;
...
}
a:visited {
background-color: #7b77ff;
}
```

Comment: after defining a i still get the same results. I need the purple colour.

Answer (score 0):

On my end, the background of all your buttons work fine (see: they all display with red background) in Chrome, FireFox, and Edge, anyway...

You don't appear to have defined

```
a {
  background-color: #f44336;
}
```

Instead, you're using `:link` and `:visited`

Is it possible that you've already used the link in Edge, and it is using the `background-color` you have set for `:visited`? If you'd like for them to not change, remove the `background-color` within your `:visited` css

Comment: Perhaps try to apply `a { background-color: #f44336; }` and see if that helps - https://prnt.sc/g8szxc

Comment: Quite strange. There's a posiblity you may just need to clear the browser's cache? https://packard-bell-scandic.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/38047/~/microsoft-edge%3A-how-to-clear-browser-history-and-cache - If that doesn't work, send over a screenshot with your Edge console open similar to the screenshot I sent you above, please.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like edge does not like text shadows with more than 4px blur.

Replacing this :

```
.shadow {
     text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #d3d3d3;         
    }
```

With this :

```
.shadow {
     text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #d3d3d3;          
    }
```

Fixed everything.
Thanks.